# Javascript & Gmail equivalents to Applescript & Apple Mail

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, gmail, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

Our company receives orders from a third party proprietary website via email.

I select an order message in Apple Mail and run an Applescript I wrote that uses applescript, awk, curl and bash to:

- evaluate the selected email message
- download any attachments to our server
- parse the paragraphs (plain text, not HTML - I use RegEx to get and set order details (orderId, customerName, quantity, etc.)
- write the order details to a MySQL database

I would like to do the same with a Google App Script, Gmail and Google Cloud SQL, but don't know what languages (Javascript? Python?) and methods are best to select and get the raw text of an order email message, keep it in the cloud, and process the order.  App Script is only Javascript I think.  I have written a little Python code, but no real apps.

Anyone have a bone to throw me?

Comment: Um, you should probably figure out what language you need to know, and learn it. I mean, you do not even know what language you need to know. You need to do a little more research I think.

Comment: Actually, I have been doing a ton of research.  My coding background is PHP, but nothing Google works with PHP. I guess my question should be "Has anyone done this type of thing using Javascript?" Python appears to be a great coding language, but right now I would rather avoid moving to Google App Engine to take advantage of it.

Comment: By the way, one can create Google App Engine apps in either Java or Python, and Google Apps Script only uses Javascript. They all have different libraries, frameworks, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Write some contextual gadget for gmail, which will work right inside of your mailBox. I am not sure if all your requirements will be fulfilled by this.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/contextual_gadgets

Using Google Apps Script, you can create a secondary UI for Gmail messages which then you can use to create orders etc.
Here are some links to the Apps Script service to get you started.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_gmail

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_html

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles

Comment: Thanks so much Waqar. I appreciate your time and thoughtfulness. I will put the tips and the links to good use.